# Showing certain values within two select menus

Tags: javascript

I want to use vanilla JavaScript.

if "js puns" is selected, hide the three "heart js" option elements in the "color" drop down menu, show the three "js puns" option elements, and update the "color" field to the first available color.

if "heart js" is selected, hide the three "js puns" option elements in the "color" drop down menu, show the three "heart js" option elements, and update the "color" field to the first available color.

```js
const select = document.getElementById('title');
let textField = document.getElementById('other-title').style.display = "none";  
const theme = document.getElementById('design');
const themeChi = document.getElementById('design').children;
const color = document.getElementById('color');
const colorElement = document.createElement('option');
const colorChi = document.getElementById('color').children;
//
//
// trying to show colors based on #design selection
theme.addEventListener("change", function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < theme.length; i ++){
        if (theme[i] === 1){
            colorChi.style.display="block";
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<fieldset class="shirt">
        <legend>T-Shirt Info</legend>
        
        <div class="shirt-box">
          <div>
            <label for="size">Size:</label>
            <select id="size" name="user-size">
              <option value="small">S</option>
              <option value="medium" selected>M</option>
              <option value="large">L</option>
              <option value="extra large">XL</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div>
            <label for="design">Design:</label>
            <select id="design" name="user-design">
              <option>Select Theme</option>
              <option value="js puns">Theme - JS Puns</option>
              <option value="heart js">Theme - I &#9829; JS</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div id="colors-js-puns" class="">
            <label for="color">Color:</label>
            <select id="color">
              <option value="cornflowerblue">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
              <option value="darkslategrey">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
              <option value="gold">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
              <option value="tomato">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
              <option value="steelblue">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
              <option value="dimgrey">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>               
      </fieldset>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code here in the question.  Don't merely link to it off-site.  Once the code changes or disappears, your question will not provide any value for future readers.  We need a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: @Amy updated now. Thank you

Comment: Excellent.  You've got a good question now.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!.

Comment: Okay now that I've had a chance to review your question, I'm unsure what the issue is that you're facing.  Could you elaborate a bit?  Are you getting errors, or what situation has you stumped?

Comment: Im trying to hide all the options in the #color select menu until the first select menu has an option.  Then based upon which ever option is chosen in the first select menu I want to display only certain options that relate.  Hopefully this makes sense.